# settings does not have attribute blit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am currently learning python from the book 'Python Crash Course'.

In the book I am currently on a project called Alien Invasion. I am running into a problem in the game after I tried to add the ability for the ship to gain speed the longer you press the button. It says that the settings() does not have the attribute 'blit' (when it calls the blitme function to draw the ship in the game).

My code is split into multiple modules which I have included below.

All modules are .py.

alieninvasionbase:

```py
import sys                                               
import pygame
from settings import *
from ship import *
from gamef import *

def start_game():
        pygame.init()
    ai_settings = settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Wars")
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    while True:
        ship.update() 
        check_events(ship)
        us(ai_settings,screen,ship)

start_game()
```

game.py:

```
import sys
import ship
import pygame
def check_events(ship):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:                                                     
                ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:                                                     
                ship.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = False
def us(self,ai_settings,screen,ship):
    self.screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    self.ship.blitme()                              
    self.pygame.display.flip()
check_events(ship)
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
class Ship():
    def __init__(self,screen,ai_settings):
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/spaceship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right == True:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.moving_left == True:
            self.rect.centerx += -1
    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

settings.py:

```
import pygame

import sys
import ship
class settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800 
        self.bg_color = (0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `us` method in *game.py* is not an instance method since it's not part of a class, so it does not need the `self` parameter. See [What is the purpose of the word 'self', in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/2745495).

```py
def us(self,ai_settings,screen,ship):
    self.screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    self.ship.blitme()                              
    self.pygame.display.flip()
```

Remove `self` and just use the 3 parameters directly.

```py
def us(ai_settings,screen,ship):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()                              
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I think it would be better to make `check_events` and `us` instance methods of `Ship`, since you pass `ship` as a parameter anyway, and also all `Ship` instances already has a copy of `screen` and `ai_settings`.

Another problem I see is that you mixed-up the arguments to `Ship`. The class `__init__` methods accept `screen` and `ai_settings`, **in that specific order**:

```py
def __init__(self,screen,ai_settings):  # <--- look at the input order
    self.screen = screen
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings
```

But you instantiate a ship like this:

```py
ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)        # <--- the order here is incorrect
```

Notice the order is incorrect. So in `__init__`, the **1st argument** `ai_settings` gets assigned to `self.screen` and the **2nd argument** `screen` gets assigned to `self.ai_settings`. **The order is important for positional arguments of a function**, Python does not check the variable name.

That will lead to the error you mentioned here:

```
def blitme(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

Because, in effect, `self.screen` is actually the `settings` instance `ai_settings`. You can check that by printing-out `type(self.screen)`. It is the same as:

```
ai_settings = settings()  # instantiated in `start_game`
ai_settings.blit(...)     # inside `Ship#blitme`
```

and the `settings` class does not have the `blit` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for finding that error for me. It does still seem like the main problem has not been fixed yet as it still show the error with the blit

Comment: @insertuniqueusernamehere I re-read your post, and I think I found the problem. I updated my answer, hoping that fixes things. Basically, the arguments you pass to `Ship(arg1, arg2)` is in the wrong order.